# How to create window constructor in python using tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, oop, tkinter

**What I am trying to achieve:**

So, I am trying to use OOP to create a GUI with tkinter in which I can create Windows that have a standard UI. Haven't done this before so I am just messing around at the moment to familiarize myself with tkinter, and OOP at that. In saying this, I have encountered an interesting situation. In the code below I have done my best at what I believe is a class based window constructor that has an object "my_frame" in it. When I run the code, I get the following output:

[Output1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPMXE.png)

Upon clicking the "Click me!" button, it packs another, identical frame to "my_frame" on the original window just to the right of the original frame and also opens a new window. Frustratingly, the new window also does not have my_frame. The result is this:

[Output2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYWy7.png)

If I keep clicking the button, new windows are produced that do not have my frame, and instead the original window has my_frame packed as many times as I have clicked the button. I would like my code to simply open a new window and contain my_frame without the silliness I have created which results in the continuous packing of my_frame on the original window while producing new windows that only have the button and not my_frame.

The code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *


def main():
  root=Tk()
  main_window = Window(root, 'RedSock', '900x500', 'Click Me!')
  
  return None

def newWindow():
  main()
  return None

class Window:
  def __init__(self, root, title, geometry, message):
      main_window = None
      self.root = root
      self.root.title(title)
      self.root.geometry(geometry) #input must be in the format of string sizexsize
      Button(self.root, text=message, command=newWindow).pack(side='left', fill='y')
      my_frame = Frames(main_window, 50, 50, '#333')
      self.root.mainloop()

class Frames: 
  def __init__(self, root, width, height, color): 
    self.root = root
    Frame(self.root, width=width, height=height, bg=color).pack(side='left')
main()
```

Comment: So you dont want multiple windows to popup?

Comment: Inside `Window.__init__()`, you need to remove `main_window = None` and change `my_frame = Frames(main_window, ...)` to `my_frame = Frames(self.root, ...)`.

Comment: @CoolCloud No, I do want the windows to pop up when I press the button. I wanted to be able to press the button and have my program create the same exact window as the initial one without making any changes.

Comment: The solution provided by @acw1668 solved my issue. Thank you for your prompt feedback. I can now figure out what makes that do what I want it to do.